# How to make a component with a runtime template in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to code a page that will have its template defined in the server. The page makes an HTTP GET to the server and get a string that will be the template.

I'm trying to follow an example I found here: [runtime-content.component.ts](https://github.com/DenysVuika/ng2-dynamic-content/blob/9fdd1c51977db70363de9aff0ab7ea46dc180a7f/app/runtime-content.component.ts)

However, in this template I'm going to have references to other components, such as `<app-hello></app-hello>` and when I try to render that I get that `'app-hello' is not a known element`.

How can I tell this component to use a certain module or recognize certain components?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to include the component references here (`declarations`):

```
@NgModule({ imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule], declarations: [decoratedCmp, ...declarations] })
class RuntimeComponentModule {}
```

And to send data add on `compileTemplate`

```
(this.componentRef.instance as any).data = this.data;
```

So your wrapper will have `data` available to be used on your template.

And on your dynamic template you can use `data` to send info to other components:

```
<app-something [content]="data?.content"></app-something>
```